# Simplifying jQuery If-Statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, simplification

I have this jQuery if-statement working. Is there a more simple/elegant or less repetitive way to write it?

“If foo is visible, add this HTML element to #message, else add this other HTML element to #message.”

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $foo= $('#something');
    if ($foo.is(':visible')) {
        $('#message').html('<strong>Yes</strong>, message one.');
    }
    else {
        $('#message').html('<strong>No</strong>, message two.');
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use a ternary operator but it wouldn't be much shorter. Plus it'd be less readable. If you can edit the HTML, you could set the content of #message there and then just get rid of the else.

Answer (score 0):

its already a small code block & I don't think there is much simplification possible but here you can define the `$('#message')` element in earlier line & use it in multiple places

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $foo= $('#something');
    var $messageBlock = $('#message');

    var $toShow = ($foo.is(':visible'))? '<strong>Yes</strong>, message one.' : '<strong>No</strong>, message two.';
    $messageBlock.html($toShow);

});
```

Comment: I like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set some variables to the variable parts of the message, and then substitute them in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $foo= $('#something'), yesno, msgnum;
    if ($foo.is(':visible')) {
        yesno = 'Yes';
        msgnum = 'one';
    }
    else {
        yesno = 'No';
        msgnum = 'two';
    }
    $('#message').html(`<strong>${yesno}</strong>, message ${msgnum}.`);
});
```

This makes the parallelism clearer.